# Dell BIOS Has Random Dollar Signs on Boot Up

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, bios, dell-xps

On my older Dell XPS 630i, I get some strange boot up behavior that is causing me to be unable to install Ubuntu 16 LTS or 18 LTS. Windows 7 runs fine with no graphical hitches at all. I don't know what to try next, any help is appreciated!

My boot screen has some strange dotted lines running through it:

[image: Dotted lines]

After pressing F12, I get to the boot up menu, which has odd dollar signs all over it:

[image: Dollar signs]

Booting into Ubuntu 18.04 looks OK, but there are some strange lines running through it:

[image: Ubuntu Boot Screen]

And finally when trying to install Ubuntu I get the following MEM_FAULT error:

[image: Mem Fault]

Comment: It appears you have a GPU that has some serious problems.  The error you got confirmed that fact.

Comment: I’m surprised it’s running windows without any problems. I thought if the GPU was acting up, I’d see more issues

Comment: DX12 and Vulcan implements hardware level support.  Theoretically, if your not using that part of the hardware, it could work.  While Windows doesn’t use that part hardware typically, but the error points to a Nvidia hardware problem.  The artifacts also support that theory